# USB-zigbee connection & programming

Tags: zigbee

I am sending ASCII character to USBport of laptop, need to give this ASCII as input to zigbee, which is to be used as a transmitter.How to accomplish this? what do i exactly need to use, USb to TTL dongle or xbee usb adapter board?

I need to transmit ASCII character  using one zigbee and use another zigbee to receive the same i.e. i need to transmit and then receive the ASCII character using zigbee 2 zigbee. Then the output of receiving end zigbee is to be fed to microcontroller PIC16f628.
do i need to program both the zigbee for communication?
do i need to program receiving end zigbee to communicate with microcontroller?

Comment: its programming related question?

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at this:
https://git.ti.com/znp-host-framework/znp-host-framework#more

It is an open source project that will run on Linux or an MCU, connected to a CC2538EM module via USB or UART. There is a dataSendRcv example application that will allow you to send ASCII messages between ZigBee nodes (running with Linux or MCU).

Regards,
TC.